# What is a "weak route" in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

When using the Symfony2 plugin for PHPStorm, I sometimes see a **Weak Route** warning:
[image: Weak route]

What does it mean?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Worked it out. The [Symfony2 plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7219?pr=phpStorm) parses the `appDevDebugProjectContainer.php` file to get route and service information. However this file is only recompiled when the web page is loaded which means newly created routes are not included.

To get around this the plugin also [parses the config files](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/261) but this is not 100% reliable so routes discovered in this way are marked as "weak". Reloading the web page will make the warning go away.

Comment: Thanks for answering your own post, 2 seconds later after googling I have my answer :-)

Comment: Is there any way to suppress this warning?  I'm getting it for all routes in PHPStorm10

Comment: OK to suppress this warning,  Settings->Editor->Inspections->Symfony->Route to turn it off

Answer (score 9):

I finally fixed this issue for my situation (**Symfony 2.8** / **PhpStorm 2016.3**).

It's similar to @Atmarama 's solution but I think my version of PhpStorm (2016.3) is different and/or Symfony 2.8.

My solution also doesn't involve the `deprecated` setting. I hope this will help others:

In PhpStorm go to `Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Symfony > Routing` and add the path to `appDevProjectContainerUrlGenerator.php`.

In my case this is:

```
var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlGenerator.php
```

[image: PhpStorm 2016.3 settings to fix weak route issue]

Answer (score 3):

Check path to file urlGenerator

For me right path is:

```
var/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainerUrlGenerator.php
```

**And after make click to button "Clear Index" above**

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I also get the same problem and in my case, because i use '/' to declare the render template instead of ":"
Changing from "/" to ":" cleared that warning in my case